# In Birt Reports - Displaying the most common string value in group

Tags: report, birt

For this example data:

```
Index, State, Food
1, CA, Hamburger
2, NY, Lettuce
3, CA, Cheese
4, NY, Lettuce
5, NY, Cheese
6, AR, Cheese
```

I would like to group by State and show the most common food for each state. So the result for the example should be:

```
State, Popular Food
CA, Hamburger
NY, Lettuce
AR, Cheese
```

The problem is I can't find an aggregation that would return the most common string.
There is the 'mode' function but it only works on integers.
Am I missing Something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

- Set up two groups - one group by
  state, and a sub-group by food
- Add an
  aggregation, to count at the food
  sub-group level
- Sort the food
  sub-group by the count aggregation
- Output state and food in the state
  group footer